# Why does GPG insert dashes into signed messages?

Tags: digital-signature, gnupg

Using GPGTools on macOS, I signed a message that looks like this:

```
- List Item
  - Inner List Item
```

The signed message looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA256

- - List Item
  - Inner List Item
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
...
```

Any line that starts with a dash (not indented) gets prepended with `-␠` in the signed message.  Why does GPG do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GPG does that because [OpenPGP standard (RFC 4880)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-7.1) requires it:

> Dash-escaped cleartext is the ordinary cleartext where every
> line starting with a dash '-' (0x2D) is prefixed by the sequence
> dash '-' (0x2D) and space ' ' (0x20). **This prevents the
> parser from recognizing armor headers of the cleartext itself.**
> An implementation MAY dash-escape any line, SHOULD
> dash-escape lines commencing "From" followed by a space,
> and MUST dash-escape any line commencing in a dash. The
> message digest is computed using the cleartext itself, not the
> dash-escaped form.